# Control imbedded figure size on Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, fullscreen

I dont seem to be able to fully control the figure size on my embedded figure on a Tkinter canvas.

Heres what i want to do. Maybe you have another suggestion, than using the embedded figure.

Im trying to make a simple script to make some visual content. Right now its just a pixel mapping of falling squares in random colors.

My problem is that i need it to be fullscreen, and i can for my life not figure out how.

It is mainly about this piece of code, i think:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))
im = plt.imshow(top.img) # later use a.set_data(new_data)
plt.tick_params(
    axis='both',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    left='off',
    right='off',
    labelleft='off',
    labelbottom='off') # labels along the bottom edge are off


# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=top)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=gui.TOP , fill=gui.BOTH, expand=1)
```

It seems that figsize has a limit to how big it goes.

Heres all the code:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as gui
from math import floor
import time

class FullScreenApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)            
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom

def flashBox(color,oy,ox):
    global j1, j2
    top.img[0+oy:j2+oy,0+ox:j1+ox] = color
    im.set_data(top.img)
    canvas.draw();
    time.sleep(t)
    top.img[0+oy:j2+oy,0+ox:j1+ox] = [0,0,0]
    im.set_data(top.img)
    canvas.draw();
    return top.img

def drawBox(color,oy,ox):
    global j1, j2
    top.img[0+oy:j2+oy,0+ox:j1+ox] = color
    im.set_data(top.img)
    canvas.draw();
    time.sleep(t)
    return top.img

def resetBox(oy,ox):
    global j1, j2
    top.img[0+oy:j2+oy,0+ox:j1+ox] = [0,0,0]
    im.set_data(top.img)
    canvas.draw();
    return top.img

def drawColumn(color,u):
    global gridsize, j1, j2
    for l in range(gridsize):
        im.set_data(flashBox(color,j2*l,j1*u))
        time.sleep(t2)

top = gui.Tk()
t = 0.1
t2 = 0.00001
x = 40
y = 40
gridsize = 10
j1 = floor(x // gridsize)
j2 = floor(y // gridsize)

top.img = np.zeros([y,x,3],dtype=np.uint8)
top.img.fill(0) # or img[:] = 255


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))
im = plt.imshow(top.img) # later use a.set_data(new_data)
plt.tick_params(
    axis='both',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    left='off',
    right='off',
    labelleft='off',
    labelbottom='off') # labels along the bottom edge are off


# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=top)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=gui.TOP , fill=gui.BOTH, expand=1)

#app=FullScreenApp(top)

while True:
    for n in range(gridsize):
        top.update()
        p = np.random.randint(0,99)        
        #drawColumn([np.random.random_integers(0,255),np.random.random_integers(0,255),np.random.random_integers(0,255)],np.random.random_integers(0,gridsize-1))
        if p > 10:
            flashBox([np.random.random_integers(0,255),np.random.random_integers(0,255),np.random.random_integers(0,255)],j1*np.random.random_integers(0,gridsize-1),j2*np.random.random_integers(0,gridsize-1))
        else:
            flashBox([0,0,0],0,0)
```

Comment: I do have problems understanding the problem and what you are trying to achieve. Is the question how to start a tkinter application in full screen (maximized) mode? How does the matplotlib plot relate to that?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that the tkinter `canvas` fills the whole tkinter window?

Comment: Well first of all my problem is that i cant make the matplotlib figure fill out the whole canvas, regardless of window size.